# Updated API docs is not loading into swagger-ui while running through docker

Tags: docker, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to load edited API docs into `swagger-UI` but when I am running using docker the updated API docs is not reflecting. I am explaining my docker command below.

```
sudo docker build -t swagger-ui .


sudo docker run -d -it -p 8080:8080 --name test-container-swagger  swagger-ui:latest
```

I have added my local `swagger.json` file into below `dist/index.html` and its working fine while running using node`(npm start)`.

```
window.onload = function() {

      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "swagger.json",
        "dom_id": "#swagger-ui",
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
      })


      // End Swagger UI call region


      window.ui = ui;
    };
```

But when I am running through docker using the given command above its fetching the swagger file from `https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json` not replacing the local file. so I need to run with my local API docs using docker. Please help me to resolve this issue.